# How to check the type of a variable in ESQL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I would like to check if a variable is a Char or Decimal. In Java, I would write the following. How would I do it in ESQL?

```
if (s instanceof String) {
    // s is String
} else if (s instanceof Integer) {
    // s is Integer value
}
```

Comment: Just a idea and may be not a good way of doing it. You could try to CAST the value to decimal. If it were a decimal, then the cast will be successful whereas if it weren't then there will be a exception thrown. You can then use DECLARE HANDLER statement or Try Catch node to further handle the exception and build your logic.

Comment: @Rohan CAST is a good suggestion. And you can use the DEFAULT option to set a flag value. CAST(MyValue AS INTEGER DEFAULT -1) and then check for -1

Comment: @lars depending on your use case you could use a Java Compute Node but do note that the elements you extract from the message tree are Java Objects but of type MbElement I haven't tried it but MbElement has a getSpecificType() method that is parser specific.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it is not possible in ESQL.

There is a [FIELDTYPE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05550_.html) function, but it does not give you the data type.

When programming in IIB you generally use the parsers to produce the message tree with fields in the correct data type, see for example [XMLNSC data types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ad67040_.html) when you work with XML messages. There was a similiar discussion [here](http://mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=70754).